# Regular expression for extracting the variable name

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to extract the variable name from a given string and replace it with something else.

For example, given this string:

> var test1 = 1; var test2=2; var test-test=1 var test_3=3;

I need to extract *test1*, *test2*, *test-test* and *test_3* and replace them with something else.

What I tried was the following pattern:

`var ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})`

I came up with it by myself, from the little I know about regex, and to my knowledge it should match (greedy) a piece of string that starts with `var`, contains letters, both lowercase and uppercase, and the characters `-` and `_`.

However, when I run this with a replace, the match is `var name` and not just `name`.

```
testString.replace(/var ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})/g, function (match) {
    return match;
});
```

You can see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HyBZy/

This itself it's not a huge deal, since I can simply remove the `var` part from the match but I would like to know why is this happening and how can I fix this.
I understood that the part between `()` is what's usually matched inside a regular expression and everything else it's part of the pattern.

A good explanation will be greatly appreciated, I'd really like to learn more about regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) you can add more parameters to achieve what you want.

The first parameter to the function, 'match', is the entire matched string. There follow as many additional parameters as you have capture groups in the regex (in your case one).

So you can instead use:

```
testString.replace(/var ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})/g, function (match, captureOne) {
    return captureOne;
});
```

Here's [a fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn2qW/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer in 3 minutes, the documentation link is the most useful

Answer (score 2):

You can slightly modify your code with this:

```
var newString = testString.replace(/var ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})/g, function ($0, $1) {
    return $1;
});
```

Trick is to use `$1` here for return statement which is matched group #1 in your regex (**which was already correct**) but you can shorten that to:

```
/var ([\w-]+)/g
```

Since `\w` means `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and `+` means 1 or more matches.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HyBZy/3/)

**OUTPUT:**

```
test1
test1
test-test
test_3
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all the variable names:

```
var str = "var test1 = 1; var test2=2; var test-test=1; var test_3=3;";

var matches;
var regex = /var\s+(.*?)[\s=].*?;/g;
while (matches = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(matches[1]);
}
```

Here's how to replace the names:

```
var str = "var test1 = 1; var test2=2; var test-test=1; var test_3=3;";
var cntr = 0;
var base = "base";
var output = str.replace(regex, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p1 + base + cntr++ + p3;
});
console.log(output);  // generates var base0 = 1; var base1=2; var base2=1; var base3=3;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/93ZHA/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with replace, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HyBZy/1/ Also, it doesn't seem to match the strings with `-` or `_` correctly. I'm starting to have doubts if this is a regex issue or a replace issue...

Comment: @BBog - I've added a way to replace the var names.  You were missing a semi-colon in your test which is why the last one wasn't matching.  I'm assuming you mean to have that semi-colon there.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your group, just get the first "*parenthesized submatch*" which is the second parameter of the callback function:

```
testString.replace(/var ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})/g, function (match, p1) {
    console.log(p1);
});
```

prints:

```
test1
test2
test-test
test_3
```

[The replace function is very well documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).